# Date and Time format not changed at Windows 10 Lock Screen

Tags: windows-10, date-time

I changed Date and Time format from Region Settings in Windows 10 and it's changed everywhere in the system, but not changed on the lock screen.

While changing, Windows 10 was logged in with an Administrator account. After making the change, I restarted the computer but no change on the lock screen.

[image]

Regards
FewL

Comment: Try this earlier guide: [https://superuser.com/questions/962432/how-to-change-windows-10-lock-screen-time-format](https://superuser.com/questions/962432/how-to-change-windows-10-lock-screen-time-format)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put **both** "short time format" and "long time format" to the format that you want. But one limitation here I find is that you can show the time in your desired format *the AM/PM mark still will not show.* Means if the time right now is 3:30 PM then lock screen will show only 3:30.

Regarding the date format Microsoft has put it in their own style and that can't be changed by trying any of the settings right now. Hopefully they'll add that functionality in newer updates.