# Weird date format in lock screen

Tags: windows-10

I have a very weird formatting on the lockscreen date in windows 10...

[image]

I have played around with everything I could find the the Language & Region settings and in the Date & Time settings but I couldn't figure it out.
Help will be appreciated as it drives me crazy...

Comment: Thanks for the edit Josh, do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock screen date format is based on your locale and your "Lock screen date pattern" (element `msLocale:lockScreenFormat`) setting.

If the lock screen rejects your "Lock screen date pattern" in your locale, then the lock screen ignores the invalid pattern and uses its own pattern: for example with the `en-US` locale, full month name, comma, space, and the partial month day (element `msLocale:monthDay`).

To customize your lock screen date format, see this thread:

- change date format on Win 8.1 lock screen:
  https://superuser.com/questions/823244/change-date-format-on-win-8-1-lock-screen/1009995#1009995